# Dialogflow intent triggering

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I have prepared a bot in DialogFlow which contains 5 intents.Each Intent contains 10 prompts(Questions).Integrated that bot into Android and displays the prompts(Questions) to the user in android and the answers said by the user will stored in the database.

I am facing the issue when the user  closes the android app but later when they open the app, the question is getting continued but the question which appears before closing the app is taking the answer as "hi" because when the app is reopened, we say "hi" to start the bot So now hi is taking as the answer for the previous question i.e. the question before closing the app.

For example, if we answer 5 questions and when the 6th question appeared and we close the app, and when we reopen the app again as I mentioned above that we need to tell "hi" to start the bot, so this "hi" is taking as the answer for the 6th question.

how to display the 6th question again even if hi is taken as the answer.....

Comment: Could you provide some code overview and Dialogflow intents screenshots if possible? It will help to understand the issue.

Comment: check the session, track the question, if 5th question has been asked do not trigger `hi` instead continue with 6th question. check all this in your client side before calling dialogflow.